# Passing Ruby strings to Javascript function params

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, module

I'm going to call javascript function when I click link.

What I tried is

```
<%= link_to ... onclick => "Pressed(<%= @addr1 %>, <%= @addr2 %>)" %>
```

**Pressed** function has 2 params, here @addr1 and @addr2 are ruby strings.

But it makes following errors.

> syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' '.freeze; end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in a Ruby string literal. To interpolate, you need `#{...}`, not `<%= ... %>`.

```
<%= link_to ... onclick => "Pressed(#{@addr1}, #{@addr2})" %>
```

Depending on the value of `@addr1` and `@addr2`, you may also need to quote them, and if they contain user-supplied input, you will also need to escape them.